# java: convert binary string to int

Tags: java, casting, binary

I'm trying to convert a couple of binary strings back to int. However it doesn't convert all my binary strings, leaving me a **java.lang.NumberFormatException** exception.
Here is my test code with 3 binary string:

```
public class Bin {

    public static void main(String argvs[]) {
            String binaryString ;
            binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(~0);
            //binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(~1);
            //binaryString = "1010" ;
            int base = 2;
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binaryString, base);
            System.out.println("INPUT=" + binaryString + " decimal=" + decimal) ;
    }
}
```

If I convert the "1010" it works great, but when I try to convert one of the other two I get the exception. Can someone explain to me why this is ?

Cheers

Comment: At a guess, it's because `Integer.toBinaryString` is unsigned and `Integer.parseInt` is signed.

Comment: Do you really mean "cast" here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int) : the `toBinaryString()` method converts its input into the binary representation of the "*unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2<sup>32</sup> if the argument is negative*".

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int) : the `parseInt()` method throws `NumberFormatException` if "*The value represented by the string is not a value of type `int`*".

Note that both `~0` and `~1` are negative (-1 and -2 respectively), so will be converted to the binary representations of 2<sup>32</sup>-1 and 2<sup>32</sup>-2 respectively, neither of which can be represented in a value of type `int`, so causing the `NumberFormatException` that you are seeing.

Comment: So how do we fix this?

Comment: Two years on and Java 8 has an `Integer.parseUnsignedInt` method that will do the trick nicely and give you back `INPUT=11111111111111111111111111111111 decimal=-1` (`Long.parseLong` as mentioned below by Eddie works pre-Java 8)

Answer (score 8):

As explained above, Integer.toBinaryString() converts ~0 and ~1 to unsigned int so they will exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE.

You could use long to parse and convert back to int as below.

```
int base = 2;
for (Integer num : new Integer[] {~0, ~1}) {
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(num);            
    Long decimal = Long.parseLong(binaryString, base);
    System.out.println("INPUT=" + binaryString + " decimal=" + decimal.intValue()) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bits for "~0" are 11111111111111111111111111111111 (32 1's).  Normally, this represents the number -1.  The bits for "~1" are 11111111111111111111111111111110 (31 1's followed by a zero).  Normally, this represents the number -2.

I tried "01111111111111111111111111111111" (a 0 and 31 1's), which represents the highest signed integer, in `parseInt` and there was no error.  But I tried "10000000000000000000000000000000", which represents the minimum signed integer, and there was the error again.

The `parseInt` method seems to expect a "-" in the input to indicate that a negative number is desired.  It looks like this method is detecting overflow in the integer and throwing the `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding all four updated methods and comparisons here for easier understanding

```
public static void binary() {

    // Gives magnitude in binary along with sign for negative values
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(-1,2)); // -1
    // Give the int value of input binary representation along with sign
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(-1, 2),2)); // -1

    // Gives signed binary representation of input value
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1)); // 11111111111111111111111111111111
    // Gives the integer value of signed binary number
    System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2)); // -1
}
```